# Two page on PageView widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

Is there any way to show to Two Page at the same time in PageView widget? basically a number of pages need to be set dynamically like for portrait 1 for landscape 2, if not with PageView is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to dynamically change the number of pages. This is likely best achieved using the `PageView.builder` constructor of `PageView`. Set the `itemCount` to 2(or else the maximum number of pages that you'll have) and provide your pages in the `builder`, returning `null` on index 1 when you only want 1 page.

Comment: Actually the case is there will be total of 300+ pages, on landscape two pages needs to be shown at the same and on scroll next, two pages will be displayed.

Comment: @SadmanSamee In that case you can still use `PageView.builder` and just return two pages put in a `Row` for every index when in landscape mode.

Comment: yeah, That's what going to do now.